# How can I save dragged & dropped elements VALUE after dropped all players (soccer manager)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag

i have a player soccer field and i want the user to create his own LineUp via Drag and Drop...

have a look at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahsce0oj/2/

this is my js code and my fiddle:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable2").draggable({            
        appendTo: "body",
        cursorAt: {
            cursor: "move",
            top: 5,
            left: 0
        },
        helper: function(event) {
            return $("<img width='5%' src='https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/shirt/1174/shirt-300.svg'>");
        }
    });

    $("#droppable2").droppable({
        accept: "#draggable2",
        classes: {
            "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find("p").html("<img width='100%' src='https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/shirt/1174/shirt-300.svg'>");
        }
    });
});
```

(there is only one position at the moment, just a test)
----> You have to move the Text (right side) into the rectangle (mean position of my goalkeeper)

but when i have my eleven positions and the "user" is done with his line up draft, how can I save his selection?

with IDs? or every time directly after he dropped an element?

thanks for any hints

Edit: I would be really happy for any other hints how could I delete a dropped player (--> manipulate the DOM—for example delete his shirt and write "GOALKEPPER" instead into a DIV or a `<p>` Element)

Comment: First, I would look at and review this example: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager I also updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/54vgb8bx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to accomplish your goals (pun intended, ha!) here. I will what I would do:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/54vgb8bx/4/

**HTML Snippet**

```
  <section id="content">
    <div id="field">
      <div id="goalie" class="drop center rear">
        <p>Goal Keep</p>
      </div>
      <div id="rightback" class="drop right mid">
        <p>R. Back</p>
      </div>
      <div id="leftback" class="drop center mid">
        <p>C. Back</p>
      </div>
      <div id="leftback" class="drop left mid">
        <p>L. Back</p>
      </div>
      <div id="rightforward" class="drop right for">
        <p>R. Forward</p>
      </div>
      <div id="leftforward" class="drop left for">
        <p>L. Forward</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- SIDBAR RIGHT -->
  <aside>
    <div id="item-1" data-type="shirt" class="drag">
      <p>Move me into the rectangle! ! !</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

**CSS Snippet**

```
.drag {
  float: left;
  padding: 0% 1% 0%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  width: 39%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.drop {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.mid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.for {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
}

.right {
  left: 135px;
}

.center {
  left: 273px;
}

.left {
  left: 403px;
}

#field span.remove:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $(".drag").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursorAt: {
      cursor: "move",
      top: 5,
      left: 0
    },
    helper: function() {
      var displayImage = $("<img>", {
        width: "5%",
        src: 'https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/shirt/1174/shirt-300.svg'
      }).data("type", $(this).data("type"));
      return displayImage;
    }
  });

  $(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var removeButton = $("<span>", {
        class: "ui-icon  ui-icon-circle-close remove"
      });
      var dropImage = $("<img>", {
        width: "100%",
        src: ui.helper.attr("src")
      });
      $(this)
        .data("type", ui.helper.data("type"))
        .data("title", $(this).text())
        .find("p")
        .html(dropImage);
      removeButton.appendTo($(this).find("p")).position({
        my: "left bottom",
        at: "right top",
        of: $(this).find("img")
      });
    }
  });

  $("#field").on("click", "span.remove", function() {
    var me = $(this).parent(); // p
    var parent = me.parent(); // div
    var title = parent.data("title");
    parent.data("type", "").html("<p>" + title + "</p>");
  });
});
```

First you will see I adjusted the `id` and `class` attributes. This allows the drag and drop elements to have much more specific IDs, and then can be styled via CSS in a more generalized manner. I also added more positions to flush out the example of how this can help when initializing the Draggable and Droppable portion.

Second, you may notice I added a `data-type` attribute to our drag item. This can be a SKU or ID from a database, name of a product, whatever. We can also change the attribute to fit the data better. But this will be how we identify what the user has selected and what that have dropped it on later.

Next, we update the CSS to work the way we might need. Making use of `position`, I can make the `#field` our boundary, so that each `absolute` element within is positioned exactly where it should be.

Lastly, a lot of jQuery code. Not a lot of big changes to our draggables. Consider now that if you have more items, this will apply to each of them based on their class selector. When we make the helper, we tack on the data attribute so that we can tact it to the drop position.

For the drop, we want to do more.

1. Accept only a drag item
2. Append in the `img`
3. Update the product / ID data
4. Create a way for user to remove selection
5. Store the original text if item is removed

It was not clear if this should no longer be droppable, but you could easily add that in, such that you could not drop a new item onto it. But then initial drop again in the remove button.

All this happens in the drop. To avoid confusion (around `$(this)`), I setup the remove button click function outside of the drop.

This should be enough to get you well along. I suspect you'll make a save or complete button. In this I would advise iterating over each `.drop` and look for info in the `data-type` attribute for each as well as the `id` from the parent `div`. You can then build an object or array to send the data along to be processed.

Comment: WOW :) It's xmas today hahaha THx SO MUCH!!!

my questions now are:

    How can I only accept goalkeppers into the goalkeeper DIV (I know i have to chagen the "accept:" parameter at the droppable section, but can i do something like "accept: #ID_of_Player" in your example "accept: item-1"

    How can I add also and Remove x Button to the "move me into the rectangle" / player name
i really want to complete the lineup Draft with a submit Button to save the lineUp result at my Databse
Can i use something like
 http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Thx 4 ya heeeelp!

Comment: sorry my last post was really confusing...

Could you check on the long answer which i have added further above as an normal "Answer"

Thanks man :)

Comment: @nbg15 if this answers your original post, you may want to consider marking it as the answer. Your other questions go way outside your original post.  There are ways of doing this, and I would suggest looking at Draggable `revert` along with Droppable `accept`. I added a lot of the elements to clarify my answer, so if you want to continue to use it, and grow the code to your own needs, that's fine, but I am not your employee. Not going to write your game for you.

Comment: I Never Really worked with stackoverflow before, But i rated your answer now positive and i also found a Solution by myself and Reading the manual :)

Comment: Here is my fiddle:

Comment: You really helped me out! THX :)

Comment: @nbg15 glad I could help. It looks like you have a good start there. There will be more hurdles, but this is what helps you learn. Those challenges and the self discovery.